# Understanding AJAX and callbacks

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've searched around the internet, and SO and I haven't managed to find the answer to what I thought would be a simple question. I've only just started getting involved with AJAX and js, so please excuse me if it appears to be a really dumb question!

How do i return html, and a variable in the AJAX callback.

Say I want to execute a database query to update a sort order. I send the sort order from my form to update.php using AJAX. I then send some html back like

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>Sort Order Updated</strong>
</div>
```

I display the success message in my div, and then I want to use something like

```
document.getElementById('sortOrderInput')['sortorder'].value = "returnedvariable";
```

to update the value in the form field. (NOTE: "returnedvariable" is only to illustrate where I want the value that was in $_POST['sortorder'] to go)

If I console.log(data) i currently see html content, and  I can't for the life of me figure out how I should also return a variable. Do I do it as some form of array containing both data types and then reference it in

```
.done(function(data) {
```

For clarity, I'm adding my entire script here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var original_content = '';
        $('.sortOrder').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'sort_order_update_ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'html'
            })
           .done(function(data) {
               console.log(data);
               var elem = $('.sort-update');
               var original_content_qty = elem.html();
               elem.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                   elem.html(data).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                       elem.delay(1200).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                           elem.html(original_content_qty).fadeIn('slow');
                           //document.getElementById('sortOrderInput')['sortorder'].value = ?????;
                       });
                   });
               });
           })
           .fail(function(){
               alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...'); 
           });
       });
   });
```

sort_order_update_ajax.php file contains

```
<?php require('includes/application_top.php');

if( $_POST ){
    $sort_order = $_POST['sortorder'];

    $sort_order = (int)$sort_order;
    if (is_int($sort_order)) { 
        $sql = "UPDATE " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " SET sort_order = '" . $sort_order . "' WHERE products_id ='" . $_POST['products_id']. "'";
        $db->Execute($sql);
    }
?>
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>Sort Order Updated</strong>
</div>

<?php 
}
require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'application_bottom.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: Firstly, `.value = "returnedvariable";` do yo understand the difference between that, and `.value = returnedvariable;`

Comment: and what is `document.getElementById('sortOrderInput')['sortorder'].value`? supposed to target? Also, if you're assigning HTML to an `element.value` expect to see raw HTML (as long as the element is an element that HAS value, of course)

Comment: @JaromandaX That was only put in to show where I wanted to use the returned value. I'm aware it is not written as "myvariable"

Comment: document.getElementById('sortOrderInput')['sortorder'].value targets the input field in the form, replacing whatever WAS in there, with the value that was sent in the AJAX request. And yes, it does work if I hard code any value. I don't want to put raw HTML in there. I just want whatever value was set in $POST['sortorder'] to be made available as a variable to place after value =

Comment: Please, show us the javascript code you tried ...

Comment: @floverdevel It's not just a case of the javascript I've tried. I simply don't understand the concept of how do I send back the value that was in the POST data, as well as an html response.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You could simply have the AJAX POST response return JSON like {data: "whatever data", somevariable: "somedata"} and then use both.

Comment: Given the "$_POST['sortorder']" I assume you are using PHP on the server side ?

Comment: @floverdevel Yes, server side is php.

Comment: thx for updating your question :) i notice that your sort_order_update_ajax.php file contains require('includes/application_top.php'); and require('includes/application_bottom.php'); which it seems that your "ajax.script" is returning more than it needs.   an ajax request should only return the strict minimum needed to the client.  usually ajax request returns JSON data type.

Comment: It's Zen Cart. If i don't include those then it can't process the MySQL query that is in the php file as the db connection, access to defines for table names etc is all made available by calling those files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the information you given us, i would answer something like this :

*serverside (assuming PHP)*

```
<?PHP
$data = array(
    'sortOrder' => $_POST['sortorder'],
    'asHtml' => '<div class="alert alert-info"><strong>Sort Order Updated</strong></div>',
);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

*client side (assuming javascript)*

```
.done(function(data) {
  // show your confirmation div like before
  document.getElementById('confirmation').value = data.asHtml;
  document.getElementById('sortOrderInput')['sortorder'].value = data.sortOrder;
});
```

Comment: But at the moment console.log(data) only returns
`<style>.block .notice.invalid{display:none;}</style>
    <div class="alert alert-info admin-product-quantity-sucess">
        <strong>Stock updated</strong>
    </div>`

How do I include an accessible variable in (data)

Comment: I followed your example. console.log(data) now gives `{"sortOrder":"20","asHtml":"<div class=\"alert alert-info\"><strong>Sort Order Updated<\/strong><\/div>"} `
but console.log(data.sortOrder) gives undefined, and the form field content is replaced and left empty. Any suggestions?

Comment: I resolved the issue. I had to do `var obj = JSON.parse(data);`and then use `obj.asHtml` and `obj.sortOrder`

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways to do this, but most easy and obvious in my opinion would be: From your service (server api) you can return an object like this:

```
{
  sortOrder: <sort order value>,
  message: "Sort Order Updated"
}
```

Then, you can use these variables as `response.sortOrder` and `response.message`.

Hope this helps! 
Please write in comments if you have questions, rather than down voting. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to return a variable from an ajax call to the parent scope (presumably the global scope) to inject it into the DOM.

The reason this is not easy to figure out is that it's impossible (at least in the common version of the language). The ajax call cannot return the data because it processes the http request asynchronously. You will need to either move your DOM injection code inside the .done callback, or (preferably) wrap the DOM injection code in another function called from your .done callback.